# Assigning Dictionary as Property Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assign a dictionary as a property? I know arrays can be assigned as a property associated with an object in a constructor by:

```
function object(){
    this.arr = [];
}
```

Is there any way to assign a dictionary as a property of an object? What would the property assignment be?

Comment: Question is not clear. -- "I know arrays can be assigned in a constructor" -- This doesn't make any sense to me. Arrays can be assigned anywhere -- "Is there any way to do that with a map?" -- What do you mean by "map"?. -- "What would the property assignment be" -- Again, no idea what this means.

Comment: The OP means object I guess, which would be `this.obj = {};`

Comment: Sorry, edit for clarification. Im looking to add a map as a property of an object.

Comment: What does that even mean? A google map?

Comment: @Andy: "map" means "dictionary" or "object".  Different languages use different terms.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I got that which is why I added a comment to that effect a moment ago. What's not clear is whether the OP knows that. He's using the terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Javascript object literal as a map:

```
function MyObject() {
  // Define an empty "map" using an object literal.
  this.map = {};
}

// Demonstrate map property usage.
var o = new MyObject();
o.map['foo'] = 1;
o.map['bar'] = 2;
alert('Foo: ' + o.map['foo'] +', Bar: ' + o.map['bar']);
```